# ps on remote Mac doesn't work

Tags: performance, macos

I have a Mac Mini (latest model I believe) running OS X 10.7 at a remote location that I can only access via SSH.

The problem is that the `ps` command* does not work. When I run it in any form, from any user, it just freezes and I can't do anything: I'm forced to close the terminal window. The rest of the machine appears to work fine, but any script that relies on ps does not work anymore.

This has happened several times now on different remote machines (same model and OS), and can be fixed by rebooting, but I'd prefer to know the actual cause so I can prevent it happening again. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix or diagnose this problem?

*`ps`,`top`,`w`,`killall` all experience this freeze, and so does `lsof` when it is run as root.

Comment: Is there anything in the log files around the point of the freeze which could help in analyzing the problem? When the freeze occurs, can you relogin on a second connection and check whether the original command is still running? Is the remote command freezing or "just" the terminal window/tab?

Comment: Unfortunately the log files rotate every 7 days, and I didn't notice this had happened until a few weeks after it started.
It is definitely the remote command. I can login on a second connection, but I'm not sure how I would check if the command is still running.

Comment: Hmm, right, you can't run ps :-( But if I understand you correctly, it doesn't happen right now?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it is still happening, as I haven't yet restarted the machine.

Comment: If it's still happening, can you reproduce and then login in again to get the relevant part of the log files?

Comment: Oh right, nothing appears in the log files after trying to run `ps`, there is a script running in the background that logs to a custom (non-rotated) log every 2 minutes, and I could see when that script stopped logging (because it uses `ps`). There's nothing actually in the normal logs.

Comment: This is going to be a major pain to troubleshoot and I can't ever recall seeing a machine fail in that way. You will want to make plans to restart the machine, have it supported during the reboot, but it's either really broken or just ran into a resource limit that won't be present after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when upgrading from OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 to Sierra 10.13.6

After checking for non Apple kernel extensions as follows

```
kextstat | grep -v com.apple
```

I found a number of Acronis True Image 2020 kernel extensions

Despite moving it from Applications to the bin I had to use their `cleanup_tool` to fully remove the kernel extensions that were blocking `ps`

Once I did that, and rebooted `ps -ef` and other commands then worked as normal.